# Debugging: Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'LoggerThread' was corrupted

Tags: c++

Debugging: Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'LoggerThread' was corrupted.

I can't find a solution :( is there anyway to fix this.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string LoginMessage = "Please Login";
    string loginsuccess = "Login Correctly";
    float x = 0;
    char afpl[6][7] = {

        "A",
        "B",
        "C",
        "@",
        "*$",
        "$"
    };

    cout << LoginMessage << endl;

    float y = 10;
    cin >> x;

    int i = /* Would be random - */ 20;

    int finalx = x + y * i;
    int temp = finalx;
    int last = temp / i;
    if (last > 5) {
        last = last / 3;
    }

    cout << afpl[last] << "|" << last << "|" << finalx << endl;
    if (finalx == 210) {
        if (last == 3) {
            if (afpl[6][7] = '@') {
                cout << loginsuccess << endl;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

There is no warnings but just a ERROR , here is the output

```
'PythonVsCSVsC++.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\MYNAME\source\repos\PythonVsCSVsC++\Debug\PythonVsCSVsC++.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'PythonVsCSVsC++.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. 
'PythonVsCSVsC++.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. 
'PythonVsCSVsC++.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. 
'PythonVsCSVsC++.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140d.dll'. 
'PythonVsCSVsC++.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll'. 
'PythonVsCSVsC++.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'. 
The thread 0x188c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'x' was corrupted.
```

How do i fix this issue, i tried finding the fix everywhere and all the solutions didn't fix my problem. Is there anyway to fix this this issue :), this is c++ by the way.

Comment: Cleaned up your code formatting a bit :)

Comment: You have Undefined Behavior here: `if (afpl[6][7] = '@') {` because `afpl[6][7]` is outside of the bounds of your array.  Also, I imagine you meant `==` there instead of `=` (writing out of bounds is what's causing the corrupted stack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `if (afpl[6][7] = '@')` is assigning to `afpl`. I think you meant `if (afpl[6][7] == '@')`. Additionally `afpl[6][7]` is out of bounds. That's is undefined behavior and what's causing the corrupted stack (writing in to an incorrect memory location). The array index starts at 0.

Comment: Hey, Thanks! I forgot that the array index started from 0 haha! Thanks for the help! appreciate it!

Comment: @inhumꬰne. Remember to [mark his answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/510616) if you feel like it was helpful.

Comment: Sorry I'm kinda new to this platform.